# Onmouseover Opacity Layer except selected block

Tags: jquery, css

I want when onmouseover on particular section to put an OPACITY #fff 0.2 layer on everything except the selected class i.e. table

Similarly as you have:

```
.tableHighlight:hover{background-color:#eee}
<table id='table-main' class='tableHighlight'>
...
```

but inversed (puts layer on everything else, but not the table itself)

Comment: I've got overlay css `.overlay{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:150000;background:#000;display:none;cursor:pointer;filter:alpha(opacity=85);-moz-opacity:0.85;-khtml-opacity:0.85;opacity:0.85}` but have to write everything else (& to NOT overlay the selected block); how to do that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LYcm9/1/

Comment: If you add opacity to a parent element, all child elements will be affected too.  You would have to restructure your HTML and do this differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got it.

```
$('#IDyouWant').on('mouseenter',function(){
    $('body').prepend('<div class="curtain"></div>'); // add a layer in front of everything
    $('#IDyouWant, .tableHighlight').css({'z-index':'10'}); //brings section and highlighted element to front.
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
   $('.curtain').remove(); // remove layer
   $('#IDyouWant, .tableHighlight').removeAttr('style'); //remove z-index from section and highlighted element
});
```

and css for `.curtain`

```
.curtain {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:#FFF;
    opacity:0.8;
    z-index:9;
}
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5Y3Hf/1/

**UPDATED:**

Remember that the element you need to be in front of everything must have the `position` property in css seted. it can be any position, in my example it is `position:relative;`, but you have to set the `position` for the `z-index` works

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However currently the trouble is to http://jsfiddle.net/LYcm9/1/ put it to work here, would work on it and reply when succeeded.

Comment: Could you tell why it isn't working? http://jsfiddle.net/LYcm9/4/  (as last thing?)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LYcm9/5/ look, ill update my answer explaining it better for you

Comment: you was forgeting to put jQuery as library. in the left sidebar the first dropdown was seted 'No-Library' in your fiddles

Comment: Look, sorry for interrupting but I've encountered critical major problem @ http://testowa.testynarkotykowe.pl/testy-narkotykowe/testy-na-mocz (the behavior is going crazy). Have you've got maybe any clue on how to fix it to work correctly? I've visited your page: all three tabs aren't working (nothing shows, when clicked). You're an expert and I think you would know in an instant. Thanks

Comment: sure, the problem is: when you .removeAttr('style') you also remove the position:relative; of #notOverlay0. you have to aply this position relative with css, not with style="" tag. and my page is under construction forever!

Comment: add this line to you .css file: #notOverlay0 {position:relative; background:#FFF}

Comment: Can it be overcome with stylling in I don't know: html code or something because it's problematic as it's dynamic, i.e. as '.x' class valid to everything.

Comment: add this tag to you html: <style type="text/css">#notOverlay0 {position:relative;background:#FFF;}</style>

Comment: I've did it, however wanted to NOT place .html directly in the <body> part. However, it is a sufficient fix: would want to find something that pushes it to .css file directly (this part of code). OK, you've helped - thanks - grab a book: foreverthemostimportant.com -- you've might need it, one day. Thanks one more time.

Comment: remove the style tag and update this part in jquery code: .on("mouseleave",function(){$(".overlay").remove();$(this).css({'z-index':'auto'})})

Comment: Yes, but when I change it on the website (locally): it ceases to work (Actually). I mean: it includes 1,2,3 and 4 when hovered.

Comment: i found you mistake. you cant aply the same script every ID you need to execute the code. aply the script tag only once, and call all ID in the same function. look this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Y3Hf/4/

Comment: Yes, you're right. It works. Thanks, one more time. You've helped, really!

Comment: One last thing: how to bring ZOOM over overlay (i.e. when you onmouseover on picture: http://testowa.testynarkotykowe.pl/testy-narkotykowe/testy-na-mocz